# Filter only character strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, filter

```
a = ["az", "1", "afasf7af", "8", "dsgsdgsg"]
[k for k in a if k.isalpha()]
> ['az', 'dsgsdgsg']
```

I find it a little neater to pass `isalpha` as a predicate to `filter` (clearer intention). However, there doesn't seem to be such a free function. Can this be achieved without introducing a messy lambda?

```
filter(isalpha, a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.isalpha` *unbound*:

```
filter(str.isalpha, a)
```

This works because an unbound method can still take an object of the same type as the first argument. This repeatedly calls `str.isalpha(string_value)`:

```
>>> str.isalpha('az')
True
>>> str.isalpha('1')
False
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = ["az", "1", "afasf7af", "8", "dsgsdgsg"]
>>> list(filter(str.isalpha, a))
['az', 'dsgsdgsg']
```